# How to stop edittext auto suggestion with email input type Programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, autosuggest

How to disable auto suggestion with input type : textEmailAddress, while using like below the auto suggestion will appear, exactly want stop auto suggestion with email keyboard.

Used Code

```
<EditText
    android:hint="Logesh"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine "
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and i tried below also

```
<EditText
    android:hint="Logesh"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress|textVisiablePassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

when using `textVisiblePassword` that input of keyboard **"@"** not shown.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Add this one in your EditText -

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textEmailAddress|textNoSuggestions"
```

and remove android:importantForAutofill="no"

Answer (score 1):

```
android:importantForAutofill="no"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
```

These two lines worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure it’s exactly what you were looking for, but I needed a way to keep the keyboard layout with the @ and shortcuts, but avoid saving the email in the keyboard suggestions for privacy purposes, as it’s for a kiosk app.

In the end I managed it by using:

```
android:importantForAutofill="no"
android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by adding `textFilter` property in your `android:inputType`?

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textEmailAddress|textVisiablePassword"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Android has great documentation, check the InputType section of TextViews [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType)

Comment: we should set Email Keyboard so should use "textEmailAddress"